# How can I dynamically allocate CPU resources to processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, centos, cpu

In Linux (our system is CentOS5), is it possible to allocation CPU resources to processes? For example, I have one tomcat application, I want all the processes and threads invoked by tomcat has p% of total CPU cycles no matter how many other applications are running. And I want to tune the p% dynamically (e.g., at this time slot, tomcat has 40% cpu cycles, and at the next time slot, it has 70% cpu cycles).

If the above is possible, is it possible to do it conservatively? I mean, even though tomcat has 40% cpu cycles, but if it's current workload only consumes 10%, other applications can use the remaining 30% CPU cycles.

Thank.

Comment: This would be done via control groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use RHEL6/CentOS6 (or upgrade kernel), you can use cgroup to do what you want to do.
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt

[https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html)

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the tool nice and niceness levels?

Rather than trying to dictate exact percentages, you might want to check into niceness levels and how to set them in CentOS.  Your applications will run as expected with the higher priority processes being able to claim more resources while the lower priority processes will not suffer from lack of resources even when a higher priority process is idle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am not familiar with nice. I have searched for a little while, I think you mean the renice command (in my situation). But, it seems that the effect of niceness levels depends heavily on the scheduler. Do you know how does the niceness level affect scheduling in CentOS? If I set the niceness level of one process to n, what proportion of CPU cycles will this process get?  Thanks!

Comment: The number of CPU cycles aren't necessarily guaranteed with nice - what it does do is tell the scheduler what has priority.  -20 is the highest priority, 0 is the "normal" priority and 20 is the lowest priority.  AFAIK, setting any higher or lower values just defaults it to 20/-20.

You wouldn't necessarily want to renice to -20 immediately, but rather check that -5 or -10 performs the way you expect.  You can see the niceness level of yours and other processes in top and ps to better tailor to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you really really wanted to do this (and esnyder's suggestion of prioritising using nice levels is almost certainly a better solution for whatever you're really trying to achieve) ***AND*** you're happy to do it at the granularity of 1/number-of-CPUs (e.g on an 8 core system, specify utilisation as a multiple of 12.5% of total CPU resource) then you could use [`sched_setaffinity`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) to set the CPU affinity mask for the process you want to control (you can do this from another process).  (Actually, I think you'd need to identify all that process' threads and invoke it on each of them).

Alternatively, [cpusets](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/cpuset.7.html) might be of interest but I've no idea what it takes to enable them or how dynamic they can be.

Comment: Hi @timday, thanks for your reply. We are actually considering single CPU case. So, the 1/number-of-CPU granularity may be too coarse for us. But, thank you all the same.